# Packet tracer error during setting up an OSPF default info metric

Tags: cisco, ospf

I'm trying to do some stuff with link backups in Cisco Packet Tracer 5.3.2. When I to set default info metric I'm getting a syntax error:

```
X1>enable 
X1#configure 
Configuring from terminal, memory, or network [terminal]? 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
X1(config)#router ospf 1
X1(config-router)#default-information originate metric 10
                                                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've read a bunch of manuals and they are using exactly the same syntax. I know that's problem in 'metric 10', but how can I made it work?

Comment: do default-information originate ? and see what the options are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PacketTracer is a simulator and not an emulator, hence the differences with real routers (and dynamips, which is using a true IOS image).

There are fewer commands supported, and you probably found one difference (because what you typed should have worked).

Try to replicate the same config with dynamips (and GNS3). It's a cpu-hog but will replicate real routers more accurately.